# CADisplayLink timestamp precision

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've been trying in vain to understand what the floating point value of `CADisplayLink.timestamp` is. Is it in nanoseconds? Seconds? What is its precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009031-CH1-SW7) states that the property is of type CFTimeInterval and the documentation for that says;

```
Type used to represent elapsed time in seconds.
```

As for precision;

```
typedef double CFTimeInterval;
```

I should state that whilst I've done some openGL coding, I haven't actually had cause to use this property yet so I'm just quoting the documentation here.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised. I was confused because I expected a UNIX timestamp, and haven't seen this sort of intervals before. Thank you! :)